# Show 2 texts same line with text-ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.parent{
    width:100px;
}
.ellipsis{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div>(AED)</div> 
</div>
```

I want to show the AED and the ellipsis in the same line. How to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use position relative on the div with text AED?

Comment: @Vivz position relative not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` property on parent `div` to achieve this and can set `flex` property on children to distribute space between them.

```css
.parent{
    width:100px;
    display: flex;
}
.ellipsis{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div>(AED)</div> 
</div>
```